# Formula for number of tiles needed to fill up predefined space?

Tags: algorithms

I've been bashing my head all day with this problem, there is no way I could figure it out by myself. Here's a detailed explanation, any help will be much appreciated:

We want to fill up the room floor with tiles. The room floor measures h(eigth)*l(ength). We have an unlimited number of tiles that measure 1x1, 2x2, 4x4, 8x8 ... 2^k x 2^k. We want to fill the space using the least number of tiles possible.

Just so you can picture it better, here's how to fill up a space of 22x29 when k = 2:
http://shrani.si/f/2d/110/32SFwfjA/floor.png

So, the problem here is not how many tiles are in this picture, but rather how I could easily calculate how many tiles I need for any h*l and k. For example 234*179, when k = 3 (which would mean I can only use tiles 1x1, 3x3, 9x9, 27x27,...). Again, any help much appreciated!

Comment: If someone can proof that the "greedy" approach always gives the optimal result, I can generate the minimum number of tiles in around $O(\log h \times \log l)$.